# Give unique timestamps from multiple file into one file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 30 files of the following format (data is dummy, just see format) :

```
timestamp,id
1,a
2,b
3,a
1,a
5,c
6,b
3,a
```

from this 30 files, i just want all the timestamps from all the files and store unique timestamps into one file in one line. 
I have written code for the same in python. but file size is of the order of 500 MB. 
So i want to write it in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following code example as one possible solution. I haven't tested it, but it shall give a brief overview of the function and the algorithm you could use to solve your problem:

```
% save all your filenames in one struct 
dataFiles = dir('yourFileNamesHere');

% if you know how many data lines you are going to read, you should
% do a preallocation of your data struct `s` here!

currentDataLine = 1;

% loop to read all your files
for i=1:length(dataFiles);
    fp = fopen(datFiles(i).name);

    % read the whole file content 
    while(~feof(fp))
        % parse the data from one line
        line = fgetl(fp);
        % read the data line as two separate strings
        tempData = textscan(line,'%s','delimiter',',');

        % store the data
        s(currentDataLine ).timestamp = tempData{1};
        s(currentDataLine ).data = tempData{2};

        currentDataLine = currentDataLine  + 1;

    end;
    fclose(fp)
end;

% when all the data is read you can use the `unique`-function
% to delete entries with an identical timestamp.

% finally store your data in one file
```